# Mobile phone emulator for end users on mainstream mobile phone platforms

Tags: iphone, android, java-me, symbian, simulator

I'm trying to develop a pc application(mainly for microsoft windows) to provide mobile phone emulation（especially on game) experience for the end users. It's like if you are an end user, you can download some mobile apps on your pc and test them on your pc rather than uploading to you mobile device before you really wanna have it.

I'm not trying to make it a device simulator with the os img installed, as there is no os img publicly available for some os, and it might not be so user-freindly either. All I wanna do is to load and parse the app installation file and simulate the look & feel of it, and help our users to make their decisions if they wanna install it or not.

If feasibly, we'd like to support the following mobile app file formats:

1). jar for j2me application(midp 1.x, midp 2.0, cldc 1.x, opengl 3d, feature phone api like nokia, sansumg, simense, motorola, etc.)

2). sis/sisx for symbian os(s60 v3, s60 v5, s60 uiq, s^2, s^3 etc.)

3). apk for android os(1.6, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.0 etc.)

4). cab/exe for windows mobile(mobile 2003, mobile 5.x, mobile 6.x etc.)

5). ipa for iphone(iphone 3g, 3gs, iphone 4, ipad, ipod etc.)

For jar it would not be such a big problem, as there are some apps like kemulator, microemulator succeed in doing this. For symbian/android, they might be no problem as they are both opensourced. But for windows mobile/iphone, they are big problems as there are no source code to reference, especially for iphone such a proprietary os.

Any suggestions or clues are greatly aprreicated. Thanks.

Comment: Please any buddy give your advice on this, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can speak for Symbian - You can't run SIS file contents on Windows unless you really go into assembler level and rewrite the full emulator.
For example Symbian emulator that comes with SDK uses separate libraries for emulator and for final build (GCCE or ARMV5) so you have to make a separate build for a program to run in emulator.

Comment: Riho, thanks for your reply. Your're right, but what I'm trying to develop is for the end users,  so it would not be possible for us to have the developers make a seperate build to run in the x86 emulator. Seems my only choice is going into the assembler level and rewrite the whole emulator, which trys to load and parse the sis/sisx file format, and then translate the arm instructions into x86 instructions, quite a lot of work, isn't it?

Comment: To put it in short - impossible. If you can pull it off then you can pick your choice where to work as most senior software developer : Microsoft/Apple/Google

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is a lot of work and your duplicating the work done by the simulators / emulators for each of the platforms.

I think there would be two main ways to do this:

1. What your suggesting and either use simulators / emulators.  (Maybe the ones supplied in the development SDK's for each platform?)
2. Use physical hardware and somehow get stream screen captures of each physical device.

Trying to write your own simulators and/or emulators, I think is a lot of work and will take a very long time and for some device types (like iphone) I don't think it will work very well.  There may also be legal trouble in writing your own simulator / emulator.

If you go down the physical hardware route, It may cost a lot of money for the initial layout.

Maybe you can do both?  Physical hardware for trouble devices like iphone and symbian and simulators/emulators for android, blackberry and windows mobile?

Comment: Yes,  What I'm trying to do is a lot of work, that's right, and this is why I ask for the suggestions of some kind people like you.
Yes, I considered about your solution 1 before, but this really makes it hard for us to get our product more user-friendly without customization.
Solution 2 is a nice idea, but as you said the initial investment is high and it will introduce the problem of network latency for the streamed captures.

Comment: I think it will come down to if your willing to spend money on this or not.  If no money, go down the emulator/simulator route.  If you are, there is nothing like running something on the real device.  Nokia have a service (or had a serivce, haven't used it in a long time), that allowed you to "rent" time on a real device that you could remote control over the web to test your application on specific devices so you didn't have to buy it.  That, kind-of seems like what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a lot answers after I posted my question on forum.nokia and google android-platform group, and the following contents is trying to complement this answer to this question, hopefully it would contribute to clarify the question for others too.

[from forum nokia](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?228104-Mobile-phone-emulator-for-end-users-on-mainstream-mobile-phone-platforms&p=858269#post858269)

*I don't want to discourage you, but you've set yourself a formidable goal.
If Symbian and Nokia with all their resources haven't managed to during the last 10-12 years to make a device binary emulator, do not expect it to be easy for a lone, independent developer (especially when the binaries may have OS/platform version and hardware specific dependenies to account for, too).
And the emulators for J2ME, Android and iPhone that are supplied in the respective SDKs, are also no easy one-man-projects, I suspect.
In other words, it is not enough to "parse the installation file" (which is easy), but you'd also have to create the whole device/platform specific runtime emulation environment so that you can execute the binaries (you can't "simulate the look & feel", if you can't run the code).
In any case, as Java (J2ME and Android/Dalvik Java) already are targeting a virtual machine, with those it is easier than native binaries that target actual hardware (Symbian, iPhone, Windows CE/Mobile). Windows Phone 7 and later, is also, to my understanding, running in a managed/virtualized environment, instead of targeting the hardware/CPU directly, so it is a bit like Java in this respect.
In any case, even for Java, it won't be exactly easy for you, as you'd need to create a compatible Java virtual machine and runtime environment.
With all the existing Nintendo, Commodore 64, Atari, etc.., emulators, the developers usually have created the hardware emulator that allows the original binaries to be executed (the apps doesn't know it is not running on the real hardware). With ancient devices with much, much simpler processors/hardware, and which no longer evolve, it is much easier - I imagine - than trying to target, e.g., all Symbian versions and Symbian based phones (hundreds of models, vs., e.g., one Commodore 64).*

**[from google group](http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/6f6339e51e4300ee)**

*Sure - "all" you need to do is read the entirety of the api documentation at 
devloper.android.com, and then re-implement everything yourself.  On top of 
that, you will need to come up with a way to execute the arm machine code in 
jni libraries, and somehow hook it into your emulation of the rest. 
When you are finished with the project, you will be in a position to write 
them.*